# Adding a separation line in Rajawali cardboard

Tags: android, google-cardboard, rajawali, virtual-reality

I got my full virtual reality app working with the rajawali 3D but would like to have a separation line just between the 2 images.

Is there any way or setting how i could achieve this ?